# Can we install Apache Falcon in HDP 3?

Tags: apache, hortonworks-data-platform, apache-falcon

Apache Falcon can be installed with HDP 2.x. But I could not find a way to install with HDP 3.x. Is there a way to install Falcon with HDP 3.x

Answer (score 1):

Please note that Falcon has been removed from HDP 3.0. Please see article in Hortonworks community for more details -

https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/97570/apache-falcon-in-hdp-30.html